# "<a href>" Anchor Tag is not working on single click of link

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I am trying to work out a `<a href ></a>`, but it is not working when the user clicks in the left mouse button, but it will work perfectly when try to open in new tab or new window using right click option. I have used the following code

```
<a href="http://www.wdmarketplace.com/itempage.php?pkey=<?php echo $products['productkey']; ?>">
                                <img src="viewimage.php?key=<?php echo $products['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $products['listitemname']; ?>" />
                            </a>
```

Comment: For the sake of clean code and to be able to help you please separate the use of scripts with the HTML tag with the help of variables. Could you post the HTML output of above script.

Comment: Please the out put here http://www.wdmarketplace.com/member_profile.php?uid=MTE=

Answer (score 3):

You have the following jquery code in your web page, which prevents the click from loading the new page.

```
               $('#nav .thumb a').click(function(){
                       $('#changeImg').fadeTo(0.5,700);
                       $('#changeImg').attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));

                       return false;
               });
```

Comment: So what can I do for that . I there any way to avoid the problem ?

Comment: I have commented the all js codes int it . But it still shows the same result . Please check it http://www.wdmarketplace.com/member_profile.php?uid=MTE=

Comment: @user1467983.  Not sure what that script is meant for.  You could remove it.  Or you could alter the script to permit you to click - I am unfamiliar with jquery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the problem in one of the js files for my application:

```
$('section [href^=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code (works in google chrome, mobile view)

```
<a href="http://google.com/" onclick="location.replace('http://google.com/'),'_top'">Google</a>
```